# Using Group in nodeJS to retrieve the count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this collection in Mongodb by the name logs which is of the following form:

```
 {
    "name": "user1",
    "timestamp": "15-03-1990 03.45.00"
}
```

Basically what I want is that the REST API I write in NodeJS should return the names and the count of the number of times a name appears.

The  Following Mongodb query works good and returns the correct values:

```
 db.logs.group({
"key": {
    "name": true
},
"initial": {
    "count": 0
},
"reduce": function(obj, prev) {
    if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.count += true.length;
    else prev.count++;
}
});
```

But in the NodeJS code below:

```
 exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
db.collection('logs', function(err, collection) {
    db.collection.group({
"key": {
    "name": true
},
"initial": {
    "count": 0
},
"reduce": function(obj, prev) {
    if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.count += true.length;
    else prev.count++;
}
}).toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.send(items);
    });
});
};
```

It returns the following error:

```
TypeError: db.collection.group is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: im not familiar with Node but this isn't how grouping works in other mongo drivers see: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/aggregation/ does this help?

Comment: I wonder if this does not come from the fact that you have a 'collection' as a collection name of a database. And 'collection' another name of the result of the db.collection('logs') query.
Can you first try to change this : 
`db.collection('logs', function(err, collection) {`
by something like that:
`db.collection('logs', function(err, logs) {`

Comment: @Metux: Tried that and getting the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

Comment: @Hughzi: I am going to give that a try.